# Select Nth Min element from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need your help :_)

I have a table `Invoice` with columns `Id, Name, Address, Total`, and I need to be able to pull Nth `Total` element.

I tried this code:

```
select 
    Min(total) 
from
    (select top(5) Total  
     from Invoice 
     order by Total desc) as Total
```

and it works, but it shows just one column without Id, Name and Address .. ((

How can I fix it and show everything?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. In this case `offset`/`fetch` is a SQL Server 2012 feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, you can do this using `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select i.*
from Invoice
order by Total desc
offset 4 rows fetch first 1 row only;
```